# Use Spotify with 2 network connections (1 x LAN, 1 x tethered iPhone)

Tags: networking, routing, spotify

I have 2 network connections on my PC here at work (1 LAN and 1 over a tethered iPhone). Now I'd like to listen to music using Spotify. Since our firewall is blocking the connection to Spotify's servers I was thinking I could route the Spotify traffic through my tethered 3G connection.

Somewhere on the net, I found the following IP adresse for Spotify servers:

- 78.31.8.14
- 78.31.8.15
- 78.31.8.16
- 78.31.8.17

So I added the following route to the Windows XP routing table:

```
route add 78.31.8.14 MASK 255.255.255.255 172.20.10.1
```

But still I can't connect to Spotify.

Does anyone know if this is the way to go and if the Spotify IP is correct?

EDIT: I can ping the given IP Adresses. Pinging any other server (e.g. google) times out. For some reason our firewall admins are blocking any ping requests (outbound and inbound). So I figure that as I can ping the given IPs my routing is working. Still, Spotify cannot login. So there must be a problem. Probably the authentication process is failing as I'm staying in offline mode. Is there a way to figure out how Spotify is trying to connect to its servers?

Comment: So spotify doesnt work when connected through both LAN and 3G.
Does it work when connected only with 3G? If so then you should be able to fix it with routing, otherwise it is another problem.

Comment: It works if I'm connected only through 3G i.e. LAN network interface is disabled. Basically, my problem is 1) is the Spotify Server IP still correct (the blog entry where I found the IP's is about 2 years old I think) How can I check this? 2) is the routing correctly configured?

Comment: After having contacted the Spotify support group, they gave me some adresses: 78.31.8.0/21, 78.31.8.0/24, 78.31.12.0/24, 193.182.8.0/24. I'm far from being an expert on this topic and I don't know what this notation (x.y.z.0/21) means. Can you please help me with this. How must I configure the routing?